# adding section and subsection titles in footnote of presentation

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I want to show Section and subsection names in the footnote of a presentation, made by beamer. Now, in the footer, I am using

`\insertsection\text{ $\quad \mid \quad $ }\insertsubsection`

to create something like "Section title | subsection title"

However, for the sections without any subsection, I will still have "|" in the footnote.

Is there any way to insert "|" after section title if only there is a subsection title to be reported after that?

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: \usetheme{default}

Comment: You can do a conditional test to decide whether or not to include the subsection titles: `\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\leavevmode
\vbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[dp=1.5ex]{fg=black}
  \hspace*{1em}\insertsectionhead\ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\relax\else\,|\,\insertsubsectionhead\fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}}}
\makeatother`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a conditional test to decide whether or not to include the subsection titles; something along these lines:

```
\insertsectionhead
  \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\relax\else$\quad\mid\quad$\insertsubsectionhead\fi
```

A complete example (to diaply the information I used a `beamercolorbox` and the `footline` template, but this is optional; use the settings that best adjust to your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\leavevmode
\vbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[dp=1.25ex,ht=2.75ex]{fg=black}%
  \hspace*{1em}\insertsectionhead%
  \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\relax\else$\quad\mid\quad$\insertsubsectionhead\fi
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test section One}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection One One}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
\subsection{Test subsection One Two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]