# Insert sectiontitle in footer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, footer

I'm using a LaTeX template for a presentation at my university and I try to add the sectiontitles in the middle of the footer:

The template-code for the footer looks like this:

```
% Footer.
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{decolines theme}
{
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\textwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,left,leftskip=2ex]{page footer}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.1\textwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,right,leftskip=2ex]{page footer}%
    \centering
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot} \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
\end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
```

[template download](https://github.com/ivangiangreco/basilea-beamer)

I managed to insert the subscetiontitles according to this description:
[tex.stackexchange footer insert subsectiontitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265824/adding-section-and-subsection-titles-in-footnote-of-presentation)
But I want to keep the 'style' of the template and just augment it by the sectiontitles int the middle of the footer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could redefine the footline template in the following way:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{basileabeam}

\title{Title}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=1.5ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex]{page footer}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}%
        \insertshorttitle \hfill
            \insertsection \hfill
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]