# Beamer -- How to add section title to the footer and keep the color scheme

Tags: beamer, themes, customize

I'm using the very elegant Boadilla theme and would like to keep its color schemes, but I would like to change the fields it uses.

It presents:

> Author | Presentation title | Date + curr_frame/Total Frame

I would prefer to use

> Presentation title | Section title | Date + curr_frame/Total Frame

I already found a solution in [Insert sectiontitle in footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369376/insert-sectiontitle-in-footer), but unfortunately it changes the color schemes.

Unfortunately, `boadilla.sty` uses very terse Beamer reference that can't easily be understood by an eventual LaTeX user. I suppose part of the answer lies in the use of the `rose` color theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Boadilla` uses the footline from the infolines outer theme. You can redefine it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\author{names}
\title{Title}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,leftskip=2ex,rightskip=2ex,sep=0pt]{date in head/foot}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}%
    \insertshortdate{}%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}


\begin{document}

\section{section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! 

Thanks a lot ! A true LaTeX hacker is hard to find.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes You're welcome!

Comment: Dear @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I changed the 3 lines for the page numbering in your answer with `\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber` from the previous answer also of yours that I quoted, and it worked alright.  Thanks again.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes If your beamer version is reasonable up to date, that change should not be necessary. The `page number in head/foot` template will expand to that in this theme

Comment: that's probably is the case: I use a Linux distro that's very conservative, and probably the LaTeX packages they have are not very up to date. But thinks are working fine, and I don't have to complain at all.